# is it a good idea to pass an action as () -> Void to a component?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to swfitUI, and I'm building a component a bit like this:

```swift
// my solution
struct TodoItem {

  var title: String
  var action: (() -> Void)?

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Text(title)
      if let action = action {
        Button(action: action, label: Image(image))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but my teammates not agree with this, they think I should not pass an action to a component, instead I should use `ViewBuilder` like this,

```swift
// my teammates' solution
struct TodoItem<Content>: View where Content: View {
  var title: String
  var content: Content

  @inlinable public init(title: String, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.title = title
    self.content = content()
  }

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Text(title)
      content
    }
  }
}
```

they said it is more SwiftUI fashion, but I don't understand, in terms of usage, in my solution, anyone use this component only need to care about the title and the action, in my teammates', the user need to care about the title, the action, and how to build the button, it is clearly that my solution is more easy to use, and I didn't see any disadvantage in my solution.

Is my teammates' solution better than mine, why?

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself reaching for AnyView, you've left the happy-path of SwiftUI. There's a reason it's listed in the [Infrequently Used Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view_layout_and_presentation) section of the docs.

AnyView breaks a lot of SwiftUI's optimizations. It exists as an escape-hatch when you have no other choice.

Your code looks like all the examples I've seen from Apple so far. `@ViewBuilder` makes sense when your goal is be a container for a caller-generated View, and you want the implementation details to be decided by the caller. HStack is a good example. If the component should encapsulate the View implementation details, then it should generate the view itself using properties passed (which is what you're doing). So the question in this case is "is TodoItem a general tool that will be used in many different ways by many different callers?" If not, I'm not sure why you would pass a ViewBuilder.

---

Your update (removing AnyView) changes the question quite a bit. In that case it comes down to my last paragraph above: If TodoItem is intended to be a generic container that callers are expected to provide contents for, then the ViewBuilder is good. This assumes that TodoItem is about layout rather than about display, like HStack.

But if it's view that is about display, like Button or Text, then you should pass it properties and let it manage its internals. (Note that Button *allows* you to pass in a Label ViewBuilder, but it generally does not require it.)

A name like "TodoItem" sounds very much like the latter; it seems like a custom view that should manage its own appearance. But the main question is: how many callers pass different Views to this ViewBuilder? If all callers pass pretty much the same Views (or if there's only one caller), then it should be properties (like a Button). If there are many callers that pass different kinds of content Views, then it should use a ViewBuilder (like an HStack).

Neither is "more SwiftUI." They solve different problems within SwiftUI.

Comment: I didn't find any doc saying `AnyView` breaks a lot of SwiftUI's optimizations, where did you find this?

Comment: From the AnyView docs: "Whenever the type of view used with an AnyView changes, the old hierarchy is destroyed and a new hierarchy is created for the new type." Avoiding that is a major part of SwiftUI optimizations.

Comment: Oh, it does this only when the type of view changes, I agree we need to use the `AnyView` wisely.

Comment: It also impacts the View hierarchy even if there are no changes. The reason SwiftUI has such complex types is that it's keeping track of the entire view hierarchy via the generic types. It uses that to be able to reason about what pieces influence each other, which allows it to remove redundant parts of the hierarchy (which is why Views can be so incredibly cheap). AnyView is a type-eraser; it intentionally removes that type information, forcing SwiftUI to keep the AnyView whether it needs it or not (because it can't prove what might be in it or below it).

Comment: It's very much like how structs in Swift are very cheap; so cheap that we can implement primitive types like Int using a struct. Adding type-erasers (AnyView) forces indirection into the system (much like classes do in Swift), breaking the ability to reason about it at compile time.

Comment: OK, thanks, but the AnyView is not concern here, we can finally eliminate the AnyView for my teammates' solution, I updated the question description.

Comment: I don't agree about the **AnyView is a type-eraser; it intentionally removes that type information**, `AnyView` surely doesn't erase the type, I prefer to call it a type wrapper, it still keeps the type of its view, I don't see any difference between `AnyView` and the others like `ZStack`, `Group`, I mean if `AnyView` works worse than `ZStack`, `Group`, why Apple create this structure in the first place, since every time we use `AnyView`, we can replace it by `ZStack`, `Group` perfectly.

Comment: The doc's description of AnyView is "A type-erased View." That's because the type is only determined at runtime, not compile time. That's what "type eraser" means. The compiler cannot reason about what is inside of an AnyView. It does reason about what is inside of a ZStack. There are certainly times you cannot replace an AnyView with a Group, such as when the type is is not known at compile time (which is why it exists). For example, if the type will be chosen by configuration data loaded at runtime. It wasn't listed in "infrequently used views" by accident. It's solves a specialized problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, with only change (`let` will not work), so see below corrected:

```
struct TodoItem {

  var title: String
  var image: String          // << this might also needed
  var action: (() -> Void)?

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Text(title)
      if action != nil {      // << here !!
        Button(action: action!, label: { Image(image) })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

About *teammate's alternate*: Storing `View` in member is not a "SwiftUI fashion"... so, fixing second variant I would store `ViewBuilder` into member and use it to inject View inside `body`. But anyway it's worse approach, because breaks integrity of UI component.

Comment: I believe Swift 5.2 just fixed the `let` problem. (Pulling from Twitter-memory; I haven't tried it recently.)

Comment: @RobNapier, "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'" by design!

Comment: Thanks; I was thinking of this, which is different: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/29786